# Count the multiple occurrences in a set

Tags: python

```
if group not in g:
    g[group] = set()
g[group].add(name)
```

goes through a list of groups with this structure:

```
Group: A
Name: Bob
```

and adds to the set the names of persons belonging to a specific group. The names in the set are unique and we don't know how many similar names there are in a group. So e.g. if there are two 'Bob' names or 5 'Mike' names, how can I count the multiple occurrences of the names as well to have something like this:

```
Group A: Bob 2, Mike 5
Group B: Jane 4
```

and so on. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

use a dict of dicts to count, e.g. as follows:

```
tralala = dict()

for group, name in [('A', 'Bob'), ('B', 'Jane'), ('A', 'Bob')]:
    tralala.setdefault(group, dict()).setdefault(name, 0) 
    tralala[group][name] += 1

print tralala
```

This results in

```
{'A': {'Bob': 2}, 'B': {'Jane': 1}}
```

Answer (score 54):

Looks like you might be better off with a [Counter](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```
>>> from collections import Counter
>>> mylist = ["Bob", "Mike", "Bob", "Mike", "Mike", "Mike", "Bob"]
>>> Counter(mylist)
Counter({'Mike': 4, 'Bob': 3})
```

Comment: And in versions <2.7, you can use http://code.activestate.com/recipes/576611-counter-class/

Comment: I tried this on a pandas dataframe having 60 million rows, works great in parallel.

Comment: @TryPyPy, I think you have that backwards. The counter class works in everything >=2.7; I just used some of those methods in Python3.7 without issue.

Answer (score -3):

```
from collections import Counter, defaultdict
```

lst = [('B', 'Bob'), ('A', 'Andy'), ('C', 'Charles'), ('A', 'Adam'), ('B', 'Abraham')]

# assumes people can appear in more than one group
def groups(lst):
    counter = Counter(lst)
    result = defaultdict(dict)
    for (group, name), value in counter.iteritems():
        result[group][name] = value
    return result