# Count occurances of a specific string within multi-valued elements in a set

Tags: python, list, count, set

I have generated a list of genes

```
genes = ['geneName1', 'geneName2', ...]
```

and a set of their interactions:

```
geneInt = {('geneName1', 'geneName2'), ('geneName1', 'geneName3'),...}
```

I want to find out how many interactions each gene has and put that in a vector (or dictionary) but I struggle to count them. I tried the usual approach:

```
interactionList = []
for gene in genes:
   interactions = geneInt.count(gene)
   interactionList.append(ineractions)
```

but of course the code fails because my set contains elements that are made out of two values while I need to iterate over the single values within.

Comment: if i understood your problem right, you might want to look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4746942/3522688).

this is an implementation of the answer
https://replit.com/@Shorotshishir/Just-Test#main.py

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this,

```
interactions = {}

for gene in genes:
    interactions_count = 0
    for tup in geneInt:
        interactions_count += tup.count(gene)
    interactions[gene] = interactions_count
```

Comment: This solution is unnecessarily time-complex. You don't need to iterate over `gene in genes` because you _already know_ what gene you're looking at from the `tup in geneInt` loop. Then, `tup.count(gene)` makes it worse because you iterate over the entire tuple just to count how many of `gene` it has.

Answer (score 2):

I would argue that you are using the wrong data structure to hold interactions. You can represent interactions as a dictionary keyed by gene name, whose values are a set of all the genes it interacts with.

Let's say you currently have a process that does something like this at some point:

```
geneInt = set()
...
    geneInt.add((gene1, gene2))
```

Change it to

```
geneInt = collections.defaultdict(set)
...
    geneInt[gene1].add(gene2)
```

If the interactions are symmetrical, add a line

```
    geneInt[gene2].add(gene1)
```

Now, to count the number of interactions, you can do something like

```
intCounts = {gene: len(ints) for gene, ints in geneInt.items()}
```

Counting your original list is simple if the interactions are one-way as well:

```
intCounts = dict.fromkeys(genes, 0)
for gene, _ in geneInt:
    intCounts[gene] += 1
```

If each interaction is two-way, there are three possibilities:

1. Both interactions are represented in the set: the above loop will work.
2. Only one interaction of a pair is represented: change the loop to

   ```
   for gene1, gene2 in geneInt:
       intCounts[gene1] += 1
       if gene1 != gene2:
           intCounts[gene2] += 1
   ```
3. Some reverse interactions are represented, some are not. In this case, transform `geneInt` into a dictionary of sets as shown in the beginning.

Answer (score 0):

Use a dictionary, and keep incrementing the value for every gene you see in each tuple in the set `geneInt`.

```
interactions_counter = dict()

for interaction in geneInt:
    for gene in interaction:
        interactions_counter[gene]  = interactions_counter.get(gene, 0) + 1
```

The `dict.get(key, default)` method returns the value at the given key, or the specified default if the key doesn't exist. ([More info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11041405/why-dict-getkey-instead-of-dictkey/11041421))

For the set `geneInt={('geneName1', 'geneName2'), ('geneName1', 'geneName3')}`, we get:

```
interactions_counter = {'geneName1': 2, 'geneName2': 1, 'geneName3': 1}
```

Comment: You can avoid the `get` by initializing the dictionary ahead of time using `dict.fromkeys` since you know all possible keys up front.

Comment: @MadPhysicist I did think of that, but is the performance of `.get()` so much worse to warrant this? Using `.get()` saves one pass over the list of keys, which might be useful for a large list (not a biologist, so not sure what is a reasonable size)

Comment: I'm not a biologist either, but if speed was a real concern, they'd be using C++ or similar, not python.